# Using graphics primitives to draw a cross as inset in graphics

Tags: graphics

I would like to draw a cross as an inset in a Graphics environment. I tried the following:

```
Graphics[{Inset[Style["\[Cross]", 100], {0, 0},{Center,Center}], Circle[]}, 
     Frame -> True]
```

[image: Inset of cross in circle]

Unfortunately, the `{Center,Center}` command for specifying the exact point of the cross that is drawn at the `{0,0}` position does not use the intercept of the two parts of the cross. Is there an easy way to produce a cross using graphics primitives rather than special characters? I have not done much with graphics yet and would really appreciate your help.

Comment: When I evaluated your code on OS X using _Mathematica_ V9, the cross was perfectly centered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice & easy:-

```
a = 0.2; t = 6;
Graphics[{Circle[],
  Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, -a}, {a, a}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a],
  Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, a}, {a, -a}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a]},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Using `Inset` ensures the resulting X stays within the `2 a` bounds specified.  The simpler red X shown, spills over slightly due to the thickness.  The cross is also shown in green.

```
a = 0.2; t = 6;
Show[Graphics[{Circle[],
   AbsoluteThickness[t], Red,
   Line[{{-a, -a}, {a, a}}],
   Line[{{-a, a}, {a, -a}}]},
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 350],

 Graphics[{Circle[],
   Line[{{0, -1}, {0, 1}}],
   Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}],
   Line[{{a, -1}, {a, 1}}],
   Line[{{-1, a}, {1, a}}],
   Line[{{-a, -1}, {-a, 1}}],
   Line[{{-1, -a}, {1, -a}}],
   Inset[Style["\[Cross]", 100, Green], {0, 0}, {Center, Center}],
   Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
      Line[{{-a, -a}, {a, a}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a],
   Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
      Line[{{-a, a}, {a, -a}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a]},
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 350]]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

`Inset` X's can be made to scale.  But first, using non-inset lines scales straight away:

```
a = 0.2; t = 6;
 Graphics[{Circle[], AbsoluteThickness[t], Red,
  Line[{{-a, -a}, {a, a}}], Line[{{-a, a}, {a, -a}}]},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 250, AspectRatio -> 0.4]
```

[image]

`Inset` lines' sizes are not affected by the enclosing graphic's `AspectRatio`:

```
a = 0.2; t = 6; r = 0.4;
Graphics[{Circle[], Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, -a}, {a, a}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a], 
  Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, a}, {a, -a}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a]},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 250, AspectRatio -> r]
```

[image]

Adding a factor to the insets can apply scaling:

```
a = 0.2; t = 6; r = 0.4;
Graphics[{Circle[], Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, -a r}, {a, a r}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a],
  Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, a r}, {a, -a r}}]}], {0, 0}, Center, 2 a]},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 250, AspectRatio -> r]
```

[image]

Comment: Using inset also makes it possible to locate the cross anywhere: `a = 0.2; t = 6;
Graphics[{Circle[],
  Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, -a}, {a, a}}]}], {1, 0}, Center, 2 a],
  Inset[Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[t],
     Line[{{-a, a}, {a, -a}}]}], {1, 0}, Center, 2 a]},
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 250]` shifts the cross to the right.

Comment: Just out of interest: why does the cross stay symmetrically if I combine it with a plot with differently scaled axes? Doesn't the `a` refer to the values of the x and y values where the lines of the cross end?

Comment: @Apatura - You could add aspect ratios to the insets, or scale them as shown in the addendum to my post.

Comment: Interestingly, the green cross is not offset on Mac OSX.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer definitely helped me understanding the use of the `Graphics` and `Inset` options.

Answer (score 3):

`\[Cross]` is rendered with a font glyph.  The center of the glyph is not absolute but rather in terms of typographic positioning.  For example the glyph for `,` will be rendered lower on a line than the glyph for `^` -- this is not an error.  If you wish to center a glyph you need to specify appropriate offsets for the third parameter of `Inset`.  For example on my system (10.0.2 under Windows):

```
Graphics[
  {Inset[Style["\[Cross]", 100], {0, 0}, {0, -0.13}], Circle[]},
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}
]
```

[image]