# PlotStyle Crosses needed

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I want the the dots replaced by crosses  in the following plot

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6.5},PlotStyle ->{Blue,Dotted}]
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6.5, 0.25}], PlotMarkers -> "+" ]`

Comment: Related: [(8454)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8454/121)

Comment: Hi Jee, have you figured out how to accept answers yet?

Answer (score 8):

Using `MeshFunctions->{"ArcLength"}` to get equally spaced mesh points and post-processing `Point`s to `"\[Cross]"`s:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 60,
  MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Blue] /. 
 Point[x_] :> (Text[Style["\[Cross]", 12], #] & /@ x)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Notes:**

As noted by @Mr.Wizard in the comments, to get equal arclengths we need to use `AspectRatio->Automatic`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> 60, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, 
  MeshStyle -> Blue, PlotRangePadding -> .2, ImageSize -> 500] /. 
 Point[x_] :> (Text[Style["\[Cross]", 12], #] & /@ x)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, as noted in [Point Renderings Slightly Off in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/125)

> *Precise positioning is not really achievable when glyphs from a font are used as plot markers*

This issue can be dealt with using the third argument of `Text`, e.g.,  `Text[Style["\[Cross]", 30], #, Scaled[{.5, .46}]]` as suggested by @Mr.Wizard in the comments (see also [this answer by Mr.W](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75342/125)). Alternatively, we can make a graphics version of `\[Cross]`

```
cross = First[First[ImportString[ExportString[ Style["\[Cross]", Italic,
    FontSize -> 24, FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]
```

and use `Inset[Graphics[{Blue, cross}, ImageSize -> 8], #] &` instead of `Text[Style["\[Cross]", 12], #] &` above.

Comment: Nice!  But it's not evenly spaced without `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point, thank you.

Comment: Also why not `Mesh -> 100` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, of course!! Thank you again.

Comment: Since we seem to have a good thing going you might want something like `Text[Style["\[Cross]", 30], #, Scaled[{.5, .46}]]` compensate for glyph offset, re: [(75342)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75342/121).

Comment: You can get even spacing with other aspect ratios using `ScalingFunctions` like I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139215/4999).

Comment: Thank you @Michael. I am still on Version 9, and could not get `ScalingFunctions` work in `Plot`.

Comment: In V9, try inserting `PlotRange -> 1.02 {{-GoldenRatio, GoldenRatio}, {-1, 1}}` with the `ScalingFunctions` in `arclengthmesh[]`.  The factor `1.02` should probably depend on `PlotRangePadding`, which is `Scaled[0.02]` by default.  Maybe it's not worth pursuing, since the way `ScalingFunctions` works has changed.

Comment: And it's different in V10 than either V11 or V9.... :(

Comment: Running the cross definition gives `Import::general: Unknown font type /CIDFontType0`. Any ideas what is wrong?